# Why does middle-clicking on a link also load in the current tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink, tabbed-browsing

For some websites (e.g. try [these](http://www.easyjet.com/en) main menu navigation links), pressing down with the mouse's click-wheel **not only opens a new tab, but also loads that link in the current one**.

Why is that?

This happens in Chrome (on Windows 7), but not in IE9 (funnily enough).

When using the right-click contextual menu, selecting "open link in new tab" seems to avoid this functionality. This makes me think it's a browser issue, and not tp do with buggy JavaScript on certain websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works with the right click, it means the website is messing with the middle click.

Thus, the website's JS code is messy.